# Where can I know key of Windows 8 metro background brush?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, background-color

It is kinda baby question but it is important for the visual appearance of my app.

When I installed Windows 8 DevPreview on my PC os proposed me to choose the color scheme for Metro UI. I preferred teal color. It is something like next:
[image]

So I have this color scheme for background and for setting background. Now I want to implement the custom setting for my app. Something like next:

[image]

But for good user experience, I want to keep my settings in the same color that system. In the current moment, I set settings background manual. But it isn't a solution because a user can prefer another color scheme. I've checked in StandardStyles and in main generic XAML file. But looks like that I missed it. I would be pleasure if anybody help with this.

Comment: Did you have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825943/windows-8-theme-color-accessing-it-programatically

Comment: @Erno Thanks, I didn't see it previous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This value is not available in the current SDK. Though the initial settings flyout pane does match the system color, you'll notice that any *custom* settings panes are usually white or a color that matches the application.

Take a look at the Bing Weather app and you'll see what I mean. All of the applications *custom* settings have a blue background (even though I personally have a teal theme).

Also, don't get confused by the "Permissions" settings. That dialog is also provided by the OS.

Comment: Definitely needs some polish on the SDK there. Even the IE Internet Options settings Popup looks completely out of place / non native with an all white background and unequal margin on all edges.