# Get Accent brush in Win RT XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, brush

Is there any way to get the accent brush in Win RT. WPF provided way to get System brushes through some static APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825943/windows-8-theme-color-accessing-it-programatically) on SO? The short answer is no, you can not get the accent brush programmatically in your WInRT app. [Have a read of this short post](http://www.irisclasson.com/2012/08/22/winrtmetro-app-q-n-a-can-i-access-accent-start-screen-background-color-in-my-app/) and the linked items within it for options.