# Change Windows 8 Start Screen Colour

Tags: c++, windows-8, screen, personalization

I am trying to make a program to change the colour Start Screen of Windows 8 periodically. I've found the registry value to make the change but the problem is that the user must log out then log back in to see the changes. Is there a way to send the system a message or something that changes the colour of start screen instantly like how you set it in the Personalization slider?

I'm using C++ as a programming language and Visual Studio 2012.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I would also like my program to change to Lock Screen picture periodically too. It would be nice if someone could share a pointer to that also.

Comment: For lock screen, look at using [LockScreen class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.lockscreen).

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it. What about the start screen, however, as that is somewhat my priority at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you could set the system theme colour, at least in a Windows Store app. You can't even read from the system theme colour, according to this thread:
[Windows 8 theme color - accessing it programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825943/windows-8-theme-color-accessing-it-programmatically)

Comment: That's definitely a blow. What was Microsoft thinking? On second thought however, if a windows store app can read system values I guess there might be some security issues. I for one would never download an app that needs accessing my system settings to work. Well, thanks anyway, I'll find a way around this without using Windows Apps, then.